# String useless character strip - PHP

Tags: php, string, numbers, character

I've got a huge problem. I made a special ID for the things in our webpage. Let's see an example:

H0059 - this is the special ID called registration number. The last two chars are the things' id.

I'd like to cut off the useless characters, to get the real  ID, what means strip the first char, and all the 0s before any other numbers.

Example:

```
L0745 => 745, V1754 => 1754, L0003 => 3, B0141 => 141, P0040 => 40, V8000 => 8000
```

Please help me in this.

I've tried with strreplace and explode but failed :( Thanks for the help.

Comment: The title of this question should be "strip a character from a string with PHP".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
preg_replace("/^[^1-9]*(.*?)$/","$1",$str) as:

<?php

$arr = array('L0745','V1754', 'L0003', 'B0141', 'P0040', 'V8000');

foreach($arr as $str) {

    $str = preg_replace("/^[^1-9]*(.*?)$/","$1",$str);

    var_dump($str);
}

?>
```

Output:

```
C:\>php a.php
string(3) "745"
string(4) "1754"
string(1) "3"
string(3) "141"
string(2) "40"
string(4) "8000"
```

Explanation of the regex used: `^[^1-9]*(.*?)$`

- `^` - Anchor to start matching at the
  beg of the string.
- `$` - Anchor to match end of the
  string.
- `[1-9]` - A single non-zero digit
- `[^1-9]` - A single non 1-9 char...can
  include 0 or any other alphabet.
- `.*?` - to match the rest
- `()` - group and remember...and use in replacement.

This regex first by passes non 1-9 char at the beg of the string and matches and remembers the rest till the end ...and replaces the whole string with the remembered thing.

Comment: simply `preg_replace("/^[^1-9]+/","",$str)`

Comment: You don't need to capture the remainder of the string. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`ltrim(substr($input, 1), '0');`

`substr` starts the string at the first character, skipping the letter.
`ltrim` will trim off all zeroes from the front.

Or, if you prefer:
`preg_replace('/^.0*/', '', 'L0003'); //returns 3`

Comment: I don't think you code will work for L0003, P0040 and V8000 - the ltrim()

Comment: @Phill: Ltrim only trims off its character list until it hits a character that is not in its character list. It works with all examples you listed.

Comment: my bad, thought he was using an array, but if it's a string value then you're correct

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you want the keys and the index of the array to switch

try [array_flip(array)](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_flip.asp)

```
$arr = array(
   'L0745' => 745, 
   'V1754' => 1754, 
   'L0003' => 3, 
   'B0141' => 141, 
   'P0040' => 40, 
   'V8000' => 8000
);

$new_arr = array_flip($arr);

foreach($new_arr as $k=>$v) {
    echo "Key: ".$k." Value: ".$v."<br />";
}

echo "<pre>".print_r(array_flip($arr),true)."</pre>";
```

Comment: I don't think he has an array available, just that he showed how the ids were correlated with the strings he has.